# When does UK visa ban start?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, visa-bans

A friend was denied UK visitor visa in May 2012 as ECO could not link the cash in account to her company. In October 2012, she re-applied adding evidence like payslip and tax clearance which ECO found to be doctored and she got banned.

As she cannot find the refusal letter, she is confused as to when actual ban came into effect? Is it May 2012 or October 2012?

Comment: The ban is from when the documents were found to be doctored, October. However it’s going to be almost impossible to get a visitor visa even after the ban expires. The friend shouldn’t even waste their time

Answer (score 5):

**Your friend was not banned when she applied in May.**

She was warned that future applications would be scrutinized and that further problems might result in a ban.

**She was banned when it was discovered that the documents she sent in October were fraudulent.**

Her ban started then. I'm not sure of the exact date, but it's probably the date on the refusal letter. It doesn't really matter. Even when the ban expires she is unlikely to be given a visa for a long period, and applying immediately after the ban expires will almost certainly result in a refusal, together with extreme scrutiny of her application.

If she ever wants to visit the UK she should make every effort to find and keep the refusal letter.